# Why is the y axis in increments of 1 rather than 90

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I want to make a sine graph but the y-axis is off, how can i change that.

Also that do the 3 numbers in the brackets after linspace mean?

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


x = np.linspace(0, 7, 100)
y = np.sin(x)


plt.plot(x, y)
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Thank You

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html

Answer (score 0):

See [set_xlim](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlim.html) to adjust the limits of the x-axis.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 7, 100)
y = np.sin(x)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,y)
ax.grid(True)
ax.set_xlim(0,7)
plt.show()
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

The three numbers in the np.linspace command mean *start*, *stop*, and *num*. I.e. it generates an array of 100 evenly spaced numbers between 0 and 7.